# Connecting stove pipe to boxwood stove

Tags: pipe, stove

I have a Vogelzang model 8x26e boxwood stove, I’m trying to figure out how to attach the 6” stove pipe to the collar, what I’ve read is the pipe goes inside the collar, but it has what looks like a smaller space for the pipe to fit over the collar, there are no holes in the cast iron flu collar for screws.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the stove is from Germany or another country the flue pipe may be sized in centimeters and not inches as here in the U.S.A. By the way, the flue pipe fits over the cast iron collar and not inside the collar to insure that the flue gasses do not flow to the outside of the pipe. Flue gasses always flow from a male fitting to a female fitting so that no flue gasses escape and to reduce turbulence.

Comment: I bought 6” stove pipe and it fits over perfect, but I need to know how to attach it to the flu, the flu is cast iron and there’s no holes for the sheet metal screws

Answer (score 0):

I would say gravity holds it in place. It looks like it has been used before and no screws were used then. But if you must try something, a full metal stainless band clamp is something to try.

[image][image]

Comment: I’ll hook it up and see what hapens, of anything I’ll try the large hose clamp, if anything just for piece of mind..lol, thanks

Comment: If just slipping the pipe over the collar does not provide enough support, you could drill and tap the cast iron collar and then drill a slightly larger hole in the flue pipe and add screws (2 would be enough)